# simple html login form using C#.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am start to learn simple C#. 
Please help me How to pass the HTML parameter to .ASPX page to .CS page?

**INDEX.axpx PAGE**

```
     <div class="title">
                            <h4>
                                User Login</h4>
                            <div class="option">
                                Sign up for free &raquo;</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="content">
                            <form method="post" runat="server">
                            <div>
                                <input type="text" runat="server" id="username" name="username" value="" placeholder="username"/>


                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <input type="password" runat="server" id="password" name="password" value="" placeholder="password"/>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <input type="button" runat="server" value="Submit" id="submit" onclick=" button_onclick()" />
                            </div>
                            </form>
                            <!-- ## / Panel Content  -->
                        </div>
```

**INDEX.aspx.cs PAGE**

```
 public partial class Login : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
        private void button_onclick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {         
            string uname = Request[username.UniqueID];
            string pass = Request[password.UniqueID];
        }

    }
```

Comment: You need to learn some tutorials on Asp.net

Answer (score 1):

The input elements are runat server and can be referenced directly, so just do this:

```
public partial class Login : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
        private void button_onclick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {         
            string pass = password.Text;
            string uname = username.Text;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

note that every server element could be accessed via their ID:

```
runat="server" id="password"
```

on the server side:

```
string passwd = password.Text;
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.aspx